# Overlapping graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

My goal is to overlap theoretical graphs (Figure 1) and simulated graphs (Figure 2). (※These theoretical curves are the normal distribution curve and the theoretical curve of the sample average). The Show function was used. However, if the i value-the number of trials-is increased(at Figure3), the curve of the theoretical function keeps getting lower or curve is broken. Could I know How to modify code of Figure3?

Figure1) Theoretical curve

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]], x], {x, -6, 6}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.5
      } , Axes -> {True, False}],
   Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]/Sqrt[n]], x], {x, -6, 6}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.5
      }, Axes -> {True, False}]}], {{m, 0}, -2, 2}, {{\[Sigma], 1}, 1,
   2}, {{n, 5}, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Figure2) Simulated

```
m = 0; \[Sigma] = 1;
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[1];
 trialSet = 
  Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], sampleSize], i];
 eachTrial = trialSet[[i]];
 cumTrial = trialSet[[1 ;; i]];
 sampleMeans = Mean[Transpose[cumTrial]];
 Column[
  {NumberLinePlot[{eachTrial, Style[Mean[eachTrial], Red]}, {x, -6, 
     6}, Spacings -> 0],
   Show[Histogram[sampleMeans, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}], 
    NumberLinePlot[Style[sampleMeans, Red], {x, -6, 6}, 
     Spacings -> 0], Axes -> {True, False}]}
  ], {{sampleSize, 3}, 1, 10, 1}, {i, 1, 1000, 1}]
```

[image]

**Figure3) Overlapped**

```
m = 0; \[Sigma] = 1;
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[1];
 trialSet = 
  Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]], sampleSize], i];
 eachTrial = trialSet[[i]];
 cumTrial = trialSet[[1 ;; i]];
 sampleMeans = Mean[Transpose[cumTrial]];
 Column[
  {Show[NumberLinePlot[{eachTrial, 
      Style[Mean[eachTrial], Red]}, {x, -6, 6}, Spacings -> 0],
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]], x], {x, -6, 6}]
    ],
   
   Show[Histogram[sampleMeans, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}], 
    NumberLinePlot[Style[sampleMeans, Red], {x, -6, 6}, Spacings -> 0],
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]/Sqrt[sampleSize]], 
      x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
    ,
    Axes -> {True, False}]}
  ], {{sampleSize, 3}, 1, 10, 1}, {i, 1, 1000, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use the third argument of [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) to plot PDF instead of the regular histogram: `Histogram[sampleMeans, Automatic, "PDF"]`. And `PlotRange -> Full` instead of `PlotRange -> Automatic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment. As you pointed out,there was option for specifying vertical axis of histogram, such as values of "PDF" etc.

```
    m = 0;(*\[Sigma]=1;*)
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[1];
 trialSet = 
  Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]], sampleSize], i];
 eachTrial = trialSet[[i]];
 cumTrial = trialSet[[1 ;; i]];
 sampleMeans = Mean[Transpose[cumTrial]];
 Column[
  {(*Show[NumberLinePlot[{eachTrial,Style[Mean[eachTrial],Red]},{x,-6,
   6}],
   Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m,\[Sigma]],x],{x,-6,6}]
   ],*)
   Show[ListPlot[{Transpose[{eachTrial, 
        ConstantArray[0, sampleSize]}], {Style[{Mean[eachTrial], 0}], 
       Red}} , PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, 
     Axes -> {True, True}],
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]], x], {x, -6, 6}, 
     PlotRange -> Full]
    ],
   Show[Histogram[sampleMeans, {-6, 6, Automatic}, "PDF"], 
    NumberLinePlot[Style[sampleMeans, Red], {x, -6, 6}, Spacings -> 0],
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, \[Sigma]/Sqrt[sampleSize]], 
      x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> Full]
    ,
    Axes -> {True, True}]}
  ], {{\[Sigma], 0.5}, 0.5, 2}, {{sampleSize, 3}, 1, 10, 1}, {i, 1, 
  300, 1}]
```